# Django - development server not serving admin static files

Tags: javascript, css, django, admin

Everything was perfectly working fine, but after a symlink for the MySQL python the admin CSS and JS disappeared.

- I tried to Symlink the admin static folder in the Django folder.
- I copied and pasted the CSS, images, JS to the static folder but it didn't work also.

This is really strange, Django documentation mentions that "Django development server automatically serves the static files of the admin app" but this isn't the case anymore. It was perfectly working fine.

Anyone faced such an issue before ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django serves the static files, but not without a little editing on settings.py. Are you sure you haven't changed these parameters listed below?

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/absolute/path/Project/App/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/absolute/path/Project/App/templates/' -> inside this folder should be your static content, accordingly to this example
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    #URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

And in your template, you should use something like this:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}templates/styles_folder/styles.css
```

Django is probably looking for these files in the wrong directory. If it can't show your files, is pretty much because it can't find them where you told they would be.

Comment: That's True. You don't have to copy and paste or add symbolic link in order to serve static files for django admin when using development server. For more about managing static files [here are the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: mmm this is really annoying. I also did the same as you mentioned and retried exactly as you wrote but i still have the same problem.

Comment: The issue is only with Django Admin, everything else is working fine.

Comment: oh it works now, I changed Django URL to /static/ it wass simply a "/". Silly me :P Thanks though.